# How do I enter a new line/move to the next line without executing command while in a shell or bash if the command has more than 1 line?

Tags: linux, bash, azure, terminal, command-line-interface

so i'm trying to follow a tutorial on creating an Azure VM and the entire tutorial is from the CLI. It is specifically using bash. I know next to nothing about using CLI so it is pretty intimdating. Anyways all the commands look like this in the tutorial:

```
az vm create \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --name myVM \
  --image UbuntuLTS \
  --admin-username azureuser \
  --generate-ssh-keys
```

But when I try to make a new line and go to that new line to enter in the argument/parameter it keeps trying to execute the command and i cant execute anything since obviously what im typing in is missing parameters:

```
az vm create \ --resource-group ShahVMAzureUB \ --name ShahVM \ --imageUbuntuLTS \ --admin-username shahjacob \ --generate-ssh-keysaz vm create
: error: the following arguments are required: --name/-n, --resource-group/-g
```

Answer (score 7):

Quoteth the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) man page

> If a `\<newline>` pair appears, and the backslash is not  itself
>          quoted, the `\<newline>` is treated as a **line continuation** (that is, it is removed from the input stream and effectively ignored).

So, you ***literally*** need a newline (press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>) after you type the `\` to tell the shell you want to enter more parameters but on a separate line.

Generally this is used for print (or even Stackoverflow answers) so you don't have one mega-line that's hard to grok.  If you want it all on one line, remove the `\` between the parameters.

Comment: Oops, missed that.

Comment: i am so confused and dont follow your explanation. literally, in a bash shell in terminal, what do i literally need to press or click to enter a new line without it executing the stupid command?

Comment: @ShahJacob Type this exactly: `echo foo` then type a backslash `\ ` then press ENTER key. At this point the shell should be waiting for more input denoted by a `>`.  Then type `bar` and then press ENTER again to execute the command (because there is no backslash). You should see the output say `foobar` even though `foo` and `bar` are on two separate lines

Comment: horribly late response, but thanks so much man. looking back your answer was super clear. thanks for being patient!

Answer (score 1):

To expand on SiegeX's answer (since I don't have enough rep to comment...)

```
az vm create \ 
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --name myVM \
  --image UbuntuLTS \
  --admin-username azureuser \
  --generate-ssh-keys
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
az vm create --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myVM --image UbuntuLTS --admin-username azureuser --generate-ssh-keys
```

Comment: While this is the final answer how do you edit the functional equivilent after the fact to look like the above, without cutting and pasting it into an editor?

Comment: @Nick On a linux machine I would do `xclip -o | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/ \\   / /g'` where the multi line command is in your paste buffer.

Answer (score 1):

For printing the ENTER in cmd we have to use the **echo.** command instead of **echo "\n" or echo '\n'**

Answer (score 1):

Use backtick `-(key to the left of q  ~ (tilde) and`  )

and not the '- Apostrophe or single quote.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to use a backtick ` instead of the \

Your code should look like this:

```
az vm create ` 
  --resource-group myResourceGroup `
  --name myVM `
  --image UbuntuLTS `
  --admin-username azureuser `
  --generate-ssh-keys
```